# Erro ao acessar indices do array pelo nome( foreach-php )

Tags: php

Não estou conseguindo acessar os índices de um array, que é resultado de uma consulta, através do nome das colunas, somente pelos números correspondentes.

```
<?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bdteste");

function verificaVencidos($conexao){

$query = "select * from tbl_atividades where  atualizado <> 'S'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
$lista_resultado = array();

while($pre_lista = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    array_push($lista_resultado, $pre_lista);  
}
    return $lista_resultado;
}


$resultados = verificaVencidos($conexao);

foreach($resultados as $print){

    echo $print[1] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[2] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[3] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[4] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[5] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[6] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[7] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[8] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[9] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[10] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[11] . "<BR>";
    echo $print[12] . "<BR>";
}
```

desejo acessar dessa forma:

```
<?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bdteste");

function verificaVencidos($conexao){

$query = "select * from tbl_atividades where  atualizado <> 'S'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
$lista_resultado = array();

while($pre_lista = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    array_push($lista_resultado, $pre_lista);  
}
    return $lista_resultado;
}


$resultados = verificaVencidos($conexao);

foreach($resultados as $print){

    echo $print['tipo_atividade'] . "<BR>";

}
```

porém quando coloco dessa forma retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Notice: Undefined index: tipo_atividade in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atualizador\atualizador-beta.php on line 23
```

já acessei outros tópicos com o assunto parecido, porém nenhum deu solução.

resultado do print_r:

> Array ( [0] => 93233 [c�digo] => 93233 [1] => 696 [COD] => 696 [2] => 3 FG ADMINISTRA��O (CORDEIRO) [EMPRESAS] => 3 FG ADMINISTRA��O (CORDEIRO) [3] => PRESUMIDO [TRIBUTACAO] => PRESUMIDO [4] => PEDRO [RESPONSAVEL] => PEDRO [5] => GLEISI.R [DESIGNADOR] => GLEISI.R [6] => DCTF [TIPO_ATIVIDADE] => DCTF [7] => [DT_INICIO] => [8] => 2019-09-24 00:00:00 [DT_VENCIMENTO] => 2019-09-24 00:00:00 [9] => [DT_FIM] => [10] => PENDENTE [STATUS] => PENDENTE [11] => [DETALHES] => [12] => [FEEDBACK] => [13] => CONTABIL [DEPARTAMENTO] => CONTABIL [14] => MATRIZ [EMPRESA_ORIGEM] => MATRIZ [15] => [DATA_VISUALIZADO] => [16] => [DATA_FEEDBACK] => [17] => S [ARQUIVO] => S [18] => [DIRETORIO] => [19] => C [EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM] => C [20] => N [VISUALIZADO] => N [21] => N [ATUALIZADO] => N [22] => [DATA_DETALHES] => [23] => A CONFERIR [CONFERENCIA] => A CONFERIR [24] => [CONFERENTE] => [25] => 1 [QNTD_PROCESSOS] => 1 [26] => [EXTRA_VISUALIZADO] => [27] => [FEEDBACK_VISUALIZADO] => [28] => [URGENTE_VISUALIZADO] => [29] => [OBSERVACOES_PRIVADAS] => [30] => N [DETALHE_VISUALIZADO] => N [31] => [OBSERVACOES_PRIVADAS_VISUALIZADAS] => )

Comment: E existe a coluna `tipo_atividade` no banco de dados? Qual o resultado de `print_r($print)`?

Comment: Olá! Acredito que você tenha que utilizar `aspas duplas`, verifiquei na documentação oficial do PHP para a função mysqli_fetch_array e lá apresenta o uso de `aspas dupla`. Segue link da documentação [PHP Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Sim @AndersonCarlosWoss acabei de verificar este meu erro, não olhei o código a undo! já exclui meu comentário.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss existe sim, eu consigo acessar ela assim se no select eu ao invés de colocar "select * from" colocar select tipo_atividade from".  O resultado do print_r são todos os dados da consulta: Array ( [0] => 93233 [c�digo] => 93233 [1] => 696 [COD] => 696 [2] => 3 FG ADMINISTRA��O (CORDEIRO) [EMPRESAS] => 3....

Comment: @NicolasPereira mesmo com aspas duplas não vai. Só vai, como falei, se eu colocar "select tipo_atividade from" ao invés de "select * from", porém eu preciso pegar todos os campos na consulta.

Comment: @Denied Consegue colocar esta saída do `print_r` na pergunta?

Comment: @Denied você executando o `SELECT * FROM` e na hora de imprimir a variavel você colocar o index dela, da certo? exemplo, execute o `SELECT * FROM` e no  `echo` deixe da seguinte forma: `echo $print[indexDoCampo]."<br>";`

Comment: @NicolasPereira você diz dessa forma?  echo $print[1]  ? se sim, assim vai.

Comment: Tem certeza que o nome da coluna é tudo minúsculo mesmo? Não seria `TIPO_ATIVIDADE`?

Comment: Acredito que a solução do @AndersonCarlosWoss vá funcionar, acredito que o campo no banco de dados seja `TIPO_ATIVIDADE`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss cara, foi isso mesmo. Estou familiarizado com o VBA que a consulta não é case sensitive, e também acesso pelo index do array.  Muito obrigado pelas respostas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembre-se que PHP é *case sensitive*; se você cria no banco de dados a coluna `TIPO_ATIVIDADE` então o PHP irá gerar a chave no *array* também com o texto em maiúsculas. Faz diferença acessar as posições `TIPO_ATIVIDADE`, `tipo_atividade`, `Tipo_Atividade`, etc. Muito cuidado com isso.

Outra coisa, seu laço para gerar um *array* a partir dos resultados é completamente desnecessário:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
$lista_resultado = array();

while($pre_lista = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    array_push($lista_resultado, $pre_lista);  
}

return $lista_resultado;
```

Ao invés disso use `mysqli_fetch_all` que já retornará todos os registros em um *array*:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

return mysqli_fetch_all($resultado);
```

E, ainda, se precisa apenas a forma associativa do resultado, você pode informar à função para não gerar os índices numéricos:

```
return mysqli_fetch_all($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```